# How to list directory files in table format and with file information through a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I'm new to linux and I wanted to know if there's a way to list the files that are in a directory and show them in a table format, with the following information: date of last access, date of last modification, file extension and size.

Comment: Welcome, what do you exactly mean by "table format"? With borders?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for not being clear. If it can't be with borders, it can be without. What matters is the information.